# Plain text reporter for Vitest

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, vitest

I am wondering if anyone has come up with a plain text reporter for vitest that works well with Jenkins CI and other displays that do not support colored text. It is virtually impossible to read in the Jenkins output or if I run the tests within Sublime Text as a build.

Comment: It looks like a bug in vitest. I've created an issue here: https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/2204

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

You need to set the following environment - variable in the Jenkins - build:

```
NO_COLOR = 'true'
```

When you are using a Jenkinsfile, it looks like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    environment { 
        NO_COLOR = 'true'
    }
    stages {
        stage('test') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'node:16.17.0'
                    reuseNode true
                }
            }
            environment {
                 HOME = '.'
            }
            steps {
                sh 'npm install'
                sh 'npm run jenkinsTest'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Explanation**

- Vitest is using picolors: https://www.npmjs.com/package/picocolors
- Picolors is using this standard proposal: https://no-color.org/

---

**Source**

https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/841#issuecomment-1048997432